# Prove the quotient A:B is an ideal of R

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals

Let A and B be ideals of a ring R. The quotient A:B = {r $\in$ R | rb $\in$ A for all b $\in$ B}. Prove that A:B is an ideal of R.

So I do an ideal test. I can show subset and non-empty but I'm having trouble showing a-b $\in$ A:B and ar, ra $\in$ A:B for all a $\in$ A and r $\in$ R.

Answer (score 1):

You don’t need to show that $ar, ra ∈ A$ for all $a ∈ A$; nor that $a - b ∈ A$ (for $a, b ∈ A$, I assume?). Since $A$ is an ideal, this is given.

In order to prove that $A : B$ is an ideal, you need to show that

- $0 ∈ A : B$ (or alternatively $A : B ≠ ∅$, which you have already done),
- for all $x, y ∈ A : B$, you have $x - y ∈ A : B$ (or alternatively $x + y ∈ A : B$), and
- for all $r ∈ R$ and $x ∈ A : B$, you have $rx ∈ A : B$ and $xr ∈ A : B$.

Comment: Oh that is what I meant to put. Edited and fixed it. I'm having trouble showing those last two bullet points.

Comment: @Kevin Where exactly did you get stuck? If $x, y \in A:B$, then $(x+y)b = xb + yb$ for all $b \in B$; since $xb, yb \in A$ and since we already know that $A$ is an ideal, $xb + yb \in A$. I guess you're confusing $A$ being an ideal with $A:B$ being an ideal.

Comment: Okay that makes sense. I wasn't sure how to show _x-y_ $\in$ A:B or _rx, xr_ $\in$ A:B. Your statement shows the first part, right?

Comment: @Kevin Yes and the second part is basically the same.